# Why does my UPS click and beep continuously?

Tags: voltage-regulator, ups

here where I live there's a lot of voltage fluctuations ( it can't be helped. ) so I bought a ups ovislink cobalt 1000+ ( 1000va) ( line interactive it has an AVR ) ok it works perfectly except it's like an alarm click beep click beep the cause? voltage fluctuations BUT it has an AVR it should remedy to the problem not make noise switching from battery to current... I exchanged it for another UPS (same mark same problem) I said ok maybe the avr is bad in this ups so I bought a ***separate*** AVR (Vmark 1500va) and plugged the UPS into it the AVR provides stable 220 output but  guess what? the UPS still beeps and clicks.. why? what's the problem? it's not even overloaded just my tv and ps4 ( I calculated). what should I do? is it possible to open the UPS and unplug the beeping and clicking devices? thanks

Comment: Could be your line frequency is fluctuating, not the voltage.  Some UPSs will kick over to battery if the line frequency goes out of some tolerance band.  This is common when operating a UPS from a generator, for example.  You might be able to remove the buzzer, but the clicking comes from the relay.  If you remove that, you'll no longer have a UPS.

Comment: but the AVR is supposed to make it stable right? since the output is 220 and doesn't not fluctuate. so why would the ups click and beep then?

Comment: Its probably broken, plug it in to a clean AC mains an see if you get the same result

Comment: both upss worked fine in the store where I bought em this is only in my house and that's the reason I bought a UPS. even the AVR.

Comment: It's trying to communicate. You need a protocol droid.

Comment: Unclear.  I have no idea what you think a "AVR" is in this context.

Comment: Automatic voltage regulator

Comment: AUgmenting @JohnD's comment, indeed part of the problem may be the purity of the line frequency. If you have a scope to look at it you many find it is a very distorted sine wave. That can cause the UPS to get confused.

Comment: so what's the solution? the power supplier said they can do nothing about it where I live

Comment: Find someone in your community that has the tools and smarts to figure out what is really going on and go from there. Just throwing more money blindly at the problem can get very expensive with no guarantee of success.

Answer (score 1):

A  UPS has thresholds for deciding when to switch from main input to battery inverted to AC output. Sometimes it is 10% range.  But if the line resistance and loading causes greater variation from current being drawn locally or from neighbors then the UPS will be unstable. All major causes  of light flicker need to be fixed or a more flexible powerful UPS is needed.

Line voltage ought to be stable within 5% and never more than 10% otherwise this constant cycling will occur.

If there are adjustments for more backlash, then the cycling rate can be reduced, or if the line resistance can be reduced, otherwise the problem is the line voltage quality at source.

A UPS is intended to correct for momentary brown-outs or backouts and not constant poor regulated line voltage.  A well regulated line voltage needs to be low impedance and long wires, bad connections or worn breakers can contribute to bad infrastructure distribution which can aggravate this problem.

Start a notebook with a digital multimeter or DMM to record  min max AC voltages. This  may be useful to understand and communicate issues in future.   Record at an outlet near the breaker panel then at selected outlets with loads switched on/off.   Learn how to use if no experience.

Comment: I see.. the voltage here varies  195-234. the thing that I don't understand is that the separate AVR shows 220 stable output which means if the ups is plugged  into it it should be ok since it's stable but it's like if it's plugged directly the the wall socket like the AVR doesn't exist...

Comment: AVR is different. It uses a controller to switch taps electronically on an autotransformer.  like a tapped variac.. so inherently noisy, but on average more stable.

Comment: +1 I'd add.. "if your line is that bad you may want to switch from a UPS to something less dependent on the mains. The life of the UPS will be significantly reduced by all that switching."

Comment: I don't care anymore I'm broke from buying the ups and the avr the ups has 1 year of warranty so it's ok. how much  time will the ups last?

Comment: @idkwtdo depends how often that relay is clicking and how many cycles it is rated for.

Comment: every second and for 8 hours per day

Comment: @idkwtdo 100,000 cycles is not atypical for a relay, but it depends on the currents involved. Best case that's about 200 days, or 6-7 months. But it could also be days or weeks....

Comment: @idkwtdo  I cannot explain any more.  Can you try a different outlet?  Change the load? anything?

Comment: I tried all of these. It's only in my house i'll just have to bear the noise... (if i dont plug anything in the ups it  becomes less noisy )

Comment: @idkwtdo the risk you take is one of those transitions may propagate through to the output and blow up whatever is connected to it. You really need to find an "expert" to come look at it.

Comment: If you put on all your stove elements and oven and the Voltage drops more than 10% I would call an electrician or power utility about a possible fire hazard in the house wiring or outside .